# Application crashes when compiled as /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS with /ENTRY:main and /MT runtime library

Tags: c++, msvcrt

i'm trying to create a simple windows application but based on a main() entry point since i need to compile it on other platforms.

I found specific directives to do this with visual studio but it seems to work when using /MD runtime library compilation, but crashes when using /MT.

Here is a complete code to reproduce the crash, it fails every time.
==> Just create an empty project with a main.cpp file and set : Projet -> Properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation -> Runtime Library -> /MT

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")
#pragma comment(linker, "/ENTRY:main")
#pragma comment(linker, "/INCLUDE:mainCRTStartup")

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int* a = new int;
    delete a;

    return 0;
}
```

This causes the following exception :

```
ntdll.dll!RtlpWaitOnCriticalSection()   Inconnu
ntdll.dll!RtlpEnterCriticalSectionContended()   Inconnu
ntdll.dll!RtlEnterCriticalSection() Inconnu
Application.exe!__acrt_lock(__acrt_lock_id _Lock) Ligne 55  C++
Application.exe!heap_alloc_dbg_internal(const unsigned __int64 size, const int block_use, const char * const file_name, const int line_number) Ligne 309    C++
Application.exe!heap_alloc_dbg(const unsigned __int64 size, const int block_use, const char * const file_name, const int line_number) Ligne 450 C++
Application.exe!_malloc_dbg(unsigned __int64 size, int block_use, const char * file_name, int line_number) Ligne 496    C++
Application.exe!malloc(unsigned __int64 size) Ligne 27  C++
[Code externe]  
Application.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv) Ligne 9   C++
[Code externe]
```

But if i use a WinMain entry point, it won't fail :

```
#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{

    int* a = new int;
    delete a;

    return 0;
}

INT WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow)
{
    return main(1, reinterpret_cast<char**>(&lpCmdLine));
}
```

I want to complile without MSVCRT external dependency, this is the reason why i'm setting /MT mode.

Do you have any suggestion ? I'm working on this problem for days actually....

Comment: You could just use #ifdef to switch between main and winmain depending on the OS.

Comment: `#pragma comment(linker, "/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS")` - You are doing it wrong. You should get your build system to ensure the right flags are passed to the compiler/linker. *Don't* put that into source files. This is also *horribly non-portable*.

Comment: This post looks to be trying to do two very different things: build a windows program with no dependency on the VC runtime vs. build a Windows program that uses the same `main` as other platforms. Which *specifically* are you trying to accomplish, and if the latter, why are you trying to accomplish it with the former. Or did I miss something (wouldn't be the first time).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The entry point is not `main` or `WinMain`, it is a function in the MS libraries that will initialize the CRT.  You `main` example does not work because you bypass that initialization.  The `WinMain` example works because this initialization occurs before `WinMain` starts execution.  When linking to the DLL version of the runtime, this initialization happens when the DLL is loaded.

You should specify `/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`, or just leave it off and let the linker figure out the proper subsystem.

Comment: The problem with the /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE is that i can see the console appearing, even if i Hide it with FreeConsole or any other way, the console will appear for an instant.
I know what i want to do is possible because some projects can do this with CMAKE, but i can't reproduce the cmake configuration with a project creation.
Here's an example : https://github.com/GameTechDev/IntroductionToVulkan/blob/master/Project/Tutorials/02/main.cpp

Answer (score 0):

Put the linker option to CONSOLE (more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/subsystem-specify-subsystem?view=vs-2019)) and that's all. 
If you don't want the console, detach from it using [FreeConsole](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/freeconsole).

The other easy solution is to have `WinMain` call a custom `main2` when on Windows and to have main call the same main2 on other platforms.

```
#ifdef _WIN32
int __stdcall WinMain(...) { return main2(); }
#else
int main(...) { return main2(); }
#endif
```